# How to assign value to a variable inside factory constructor without making it static?

Tags: flutter, dart

```
class Product {
  final int id;
  final String name;

  // this is given value at some later stage
  String downloadUrl;

  Product(
    this.id,
    this.name,
  );

  factory Product.fromMap(Map data) {

    // how to assign value to downloadUrl without making it static
    downloadUrl = data["downloadUrl"]; // error

    return Product(
      data['id'],
      data['name'],
    );
  }
}
```

I give `id` and `name` when creating `Product`, however, I also have `downloadUrl` field which will be given value later in future.

**Problem:**

In factory constructor, when I get `data`, I also need to initialise `downloadUrl` field but I can't do that in factory constructor,  for that I need to make `downloadUrl` static but that beats my purpose. How can I then assign a value to it from `data`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  factory Product.fromMap(Map data) {
    return Product(
      data['id'],
      data['name'],
    )..downloadUrl = data["downloadUrl"];
  }
```

Comment: That's great, amazing job

Answer (score 1):

Add the `downloadUrl` to your constructor.

you can try this on [Dartpad](https://dartpad.dev/)

```
class Product {
  final int id;
  final String name;
  String downloadUrl;

  Product(
    this.id,
    this.name,
    this.downloadUrl,
  );

  factory Product.fromMap(Map data) {   
    return Product(
      data['id'],
      data['name'],
      null, 
    );
  }
}


void main() {

  Product _product = Product(1, 'abc', null);
  _product.downloadUrl = 'https://flutter.dev/';
  print(_product.downloadUrl);

}
```

Comment: I think you misunderstood the question, please read it again.

Answer (score 0):

I think I can remove factory constructor and make it a method instead. Like:

```
Product fromMap(Map data) {
  downloadUrl = data["downloadUrl"]; // works

  return Product(
    data['id'],
    data['name'],
  );
}
```

*This seems like a workaround, I am still happy to accept others answer.*